# Reverse Guess-Game tip between two numbers

Tags: android

I'd like to build a reverse guess-game. (The player has a number in his mind, and the program tries to guess the number. You have three buttons. One button for a smaller tip, one for a bigger and one for the correct.) My app is generating the numbers on keypress, but the problem, that it doesn't remember my buttons I pressed. So for example the program tips number 50. I click "Smaller" button, it generates a smaller number, for example 35. I click "Bigger" button, and it can generate 80 or 90, even if I pressed "Smaller" for 50. How could I make the program "remember" the choices? Thank you :) Best regards!
Sorry if I'm unclear, but I'm beginner.

This is my onclick:
`public void lowerClick(View v) {
        tip = randomGenerator.nextInt(( highest + 1 ) - lowest ) + lowest;
        textTip.setText(Integer.toString(tip));
{`

The only problem is how I am supposed to change the *highest* and *lowest* parts and if I have to add anything to the program. I hope It's clear now. :) And thank you for your cooperation and understanding.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question as it is currently is not realy possible to answer. Build a minimal example, show a minimal code example that clearly shows the problem and explain what you expect and what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tip:** In the future, you should post any code you already have to show effort and avoid downvotes.  However, I'll interpret this post as a general algorithm question.

You'll want two variables:

- High Range: The highest possible number the user can be thinking of.
- Low Range: The lowest possible number the user can be thinking of.

If the program guesses 50 and the user clicks *Smaller*, set the high range to 50, as you know the number must be under 50 from that point on.

If the program guesses 35 next, and the user clicks *Bigger*, set the low range to 35.

Always guess only numbers between the low range and high range, updating at each step.  It's probably best to guess the point halfway in between the high and low range to maximize your chances.  This would be somewhat of a *binary search* approach for guessing a number.